# Right spectral gap of vector of two independent Markov chains

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, sp.spectral-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_i)$ be a stationary Markov chain on $S$ (a potentially uncountable space with a Borel sigma algebra) with stationary distribution $\pi$ and transition kernel $P$. Let $(Y_i)$ be a stationary Markov chain with the same stationary distribution and transition kernel, independent of $(X_i)$. Then $((X_i, Y_i))$ is also a stationary Markov chain, with stationary distribution $\pi'$ and transition kernel $P'$. I suppose it's straightforward that $\pi' = \pi\times \pi$ is just the product measure on $S^2$. For $P'$ we have
$$P'((x,y), A\times B) = P(x, A)\cdot P(y, B),$$
so that $P'((x,y), \cdot)$ is a product measure as well.
Now suppose $P$ has positive right spectral gap $1-\lambda_r>0.$ $\lambda_r$ here is the supremum of the spectrum of $(P+P^*)/2$, which we view as an operator
$$A_2\to A_2,\quad \text{ where }\quad A_2:=\{f\in \mathcal{L}^2(\pi): \pi(f)=0\} \quad\text{ and }\quad Pf:=\int f(x)P(\cdot, dx).$$
I want to find the right spectral gap of $P'$, preferably in terms of $\lambda_r$. How could I calculate this?

If that is difficult, is there perhaps an easier way to show that the right spectral gap of $P'$ is also positive? That is my eventual goal.

My initial strategy to prove this claim was as follows: suppose $1$ is in the spectrum of $(P'+(P')^*)/2$, then $(P' + (P')^*)/2 - I$ has an inverse on $A_2':=\{f\in\mathcal{L}^2(\pi'): \pi'(f)=0\}$. I wanted to show that this induces an inverse of $(P+P^*)/2-I$ on $A_2$ via the embedding
$$e: A_2\to A_2', \quad f\,\mapsto\, ((x,y)\mapsto f(x)).$$
However, I haven't quite been able to complete the proof.

Any advice, or perhaps a reference on basic facts for product Markov chains like this on general state spaces?